# What do I need to be able to send mass SMTP email efficiently?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, email-server, spam

I am creating a web application that allows users to send broadcast emails to a list of subscribers.  Essentially, it's a mass emailer and autoresponder, like AWeber or Constant Contact or MailChimp.

The server that we were planning on hosting this application on is InMotion Hosting's "Essential" Dedicated Server, I have included the specs on it below in case they are relevant.  I have spoken with InMotion Hosting's support and they say that this server can send unlimited emails (no limit) with no extra cost.  However, I am unsure if this is really a good solution because people are paying me for this service and therefore I need to give them great deliverability, and it has to be reliable and not get shut down or blacklisted, because then I can't provide customer's what they are paying for.  I also don't know if it's smarter (for spam reasons) to have multiple IP addresses to send from, and if so, I don't know if it's possible to split a server into multiple SMTP IP addresses?

I have seen other third party services out there, such as sendgrid and mailgun, but they are too expensive to work within our price point (they would literally take about 25% or revenue).    The question I can't seem to find the answer to is how I could eliminate this potential cost by doing it myself, using our own server.  I want to know what I need to do to be able to have a high quality email sender without the PER EMAIL costs!  If it's something that is a static monthly cost, that's actually ok in this situation, I just don't like the PER-EMAIL cost because it forces me to put limits on things.  Thanks in advance for any help!

**Server Specs:
Intel® Core® E2220/E5400
2C/2T, 2GB RAM
2x160GB HDD, 4TB Data Transfer**

Comment: Holy crap that server is a ripoff. I wouldn't expect to pay more than $40/month for those specs. [Do some more shopping.](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?f=36)

Comment: Boting to close - another not too competent end user that ends up with a server and tries to bypass the need for a real admin (or knowing what one is doing with servers). As per site rules - learn the basics how email work (and that includes these days why it is not a good idea to send out mass emails without staff on hand to clean up the mess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I could eliminate this potential cost by doing it myself,

You can not. You busines model is broken. Seriously.

> I have seen other third party services out there, such as sendgrid and mailgun, but they are 
>   too expensive to work within our price poin

I recently looked at taxis - opening a taxi company. Seems good, just the d*** fuel cost. How can I run a car without fuel?

Your problem starts right here:

> The server that we were planning on hosting

TO send mass mails you need:

- ServerS - that is plural. Email is quite heavy once you reach hundreds of thousands per hour.
- A competent admin that will work day and night to keep you off blacklists as some idiots along the line will complain about the emails and totally forget that they did sign up, which will produce trouble left and right.

Running mass email is a resource intensive business. SO, either you fail - as a business -and have only a trickle of emails going out from very few small customers of yours, or you will run into all the proble mthat are the reas on bulk email services cost so much.

And like a car uses fuel per km, you will learn that there is a cost per item processed. A flat fee will have to be based on the max resources you can use and I beg you would start whining how you get ripped off the moment you get a flat fee offer.

So, adjust your business model. Outsource the email sending or - start hiring competent people. Competent in running a bulk email service. This really IS work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I was not trying to "whine" or sound like an idiot.  Your answer was good, because now I know that I can't without a lot more capital.  At least I KNOW that now, before I asked the question I wasn't sure.  Thank you for clearing this up for me. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Do nut underestaimte the amount of idiocy and paperwork. Paperwork as you will need to get refgistered with major email providers or they block you, idiocy as you WILL have a certain amount of people complaining about getting spam - regardless how legit your customers are. SOME people are idiots. Sadly as bulk email provider, guess who has to clean up the mess they get you into ;) Hint - it is you ;) THis is why those companies charge like that.